# How to create unity UI blur shader that works in HDRP and VR and blurs UI?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blur, virtual-reality

over past few days we have been trying to find a solution on how to create blur shader in unity, either by script or shader and material. Doing this in version 2021.3.4, we managed to create a working one with the following properties:

[image: material in editor]
[image: material properties]

There is a bunch on tutorials how to create blur in HDRP and all of them blurs objects in background. What we need to achieve is blur that would also blur UI, as we want to use it in menu, hence the need for UI blur.

[image: menu]

Thus we managed to create blur that works in HDRP and VR on background content, but not on the UI. As we are unable to find solution for this, we decided to ask here - is it possible to create shader or script, that we can apply as material to an object that will blur UI in HDRP and also work in VR?

EDIT: I know this question has been asked before except its for a virtual reality. There are cases when desktop things do not work in VR, so I am posting the question anyway.

We went trough other assets provided at unity store, but all the shaders work the same way - all of them blur content behind them, so using them for UI does not work. They need 3D object to blur them.

As for creatung shaders ourself, even the tutorials do not offer way to create such shader, only the one we managed to create alredy.

Using an extra camera in the scene also did not work, we have tried that as well.

Trough and trough, we slowly ran out of options, that why I am posting here.

Comment: If your UI is part of the world or screen space surely you could put a plane between the camera and the ui and blur it?

Comment: That was the intended workaround, but there are explicit UI parts where I can't do that and have to use canvas.

Comment: well screen and world still use canvas.. but. ok

Comment: The issue is that the blur does not work on canvas, only objects. here is a picture of what the blur does - it does not show UI elements, still blurs table as 3D object. https://ibb.co/186jQZT

Comment: Not that familiar with the HD pipeline but traditionally to solve UI issues like blur, glow etc it's often easier and more performant / system independant to make that in the art (textures) than shader it. Is that an option for you?

Comment: Unfortunetly, no. Some animated parts need to have opacity  without image, see the last image above.